# Checking authorization by role

Tags: php, authorization

Just wondering if my

```
else {return false;}
```

statements are superfluous... do I just need one `return true;` here?

```
function has_access() {
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $role = get_current_user_role();
        $admins = array(
            'Administrator',
            'Agent',
            'Contributor',
        );

        if (in_array($role, $admins)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd replace the conditions with guard clauses. ([Flattening Arrow Code](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/01/flattening-arrow-code.html))

```
function has_access() {
    if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
        return false;
    }
    $role = get_current_user_role();
    $admins = array(
        'Administrator',
        'Agent',
        'Contributor',
    );

    if (in_array($role, $admins)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is really pointless:

```
if (in_array($role, $admins)) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

when you can just call

```
return in_array($role, $admins);
```

So:

```
function has_access() {
    if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
        return false;
    }

    $role = get_current_user_role();
    $admins = array(
        'Administrator',
        'Agent',
        'Contributor',
    );

    return in_array($role, $admins);
}
```